# Java Simpledateformat seems to ignore string once matches the pattern

Tags: java, simpledateformat

**`SimpleDateFormat`** seems to ignore the strings in the matching string once it has found the matching pattern.

For example: the pattern `"yyyyMMddHHmm"` is matching `201601251531oi` which I suppose it should not. However this `20160125153133` fails which is exactly right.
I tried to `setLenient` as `true` and has no effect. I know we can add another check for number of digits (regex), but is there way to strictly make this pattern only work using **`SimpleDateFormat`** alone ?

```
public static boolean isValidDateTimeFormat(String anyString,
                    String dateTimePattern) {
                 // here the pattern is 'yyyyMMddHHmm'
                SimpleDateFormat datePattern = new SimpleDateFormat(dateTimePattern); 
                datePattern.setLenient(false); // no difference
                try {
                    datePattern.parse(anyString);
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception pe){
                    return false;
                }
      }
```

Comment: Just do it the way you're already thinking. This is probably the best way

Comment: @keppil if it is duplicate then point those, rather than just marking as duplicate. I did search before adding this question and there are numerous questions in SimpleDateFormat and none of them I had seen provide the answer.

Comment: @ControlAltDel ok I think if no other way then this is the better way :)

Comment: Don't you agree that this is a duplicate to the question I linked to? It sounds the same to me, and the answer is the same as you got here, only more complete and with suggestions for workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as stated by @ControlAltDel in the comments SimpleDateFormat won't work this way.  You'll either need to:

1. Add additional validation
2. Decide that the extra characters are "ok" and use the data that SimpleDateFormat parses out